# How to create a form with repeated rows in a grid with Orbeon?

Tags: web-services, orbeon, xforms

Is it possible to have repeating data in a grid with lots of fields in a table-like format, i.e. with several columns on each row, and a *totals* row that calculates the sum? If not, are there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. And I think you'll find the information you need on how to do this in this blog post: [Spreadsheet-like forms](http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/10/spreadsheet-like-forms.html). I could copy part of the post here, but think you're better of reading the whole thing.

Comment: I forgot to add that grid is repeated too, is it still possible?

Comment: I've made a picture to show how it should works: http://imageshack.us/f/571/6du2.jpg/ Part with solid rectangle will be repeated, dotted rectangle is already repeated. Sum is the sum from value fields. Whole grid can be repeated to (top left corner)

Comment: @witek At this point, you can't have repeated grids, just repeated rows in a grid. However we're planning to implement repeated sections soon (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1289), so this will also allow you to have repeated grids.

Comment: @avernet  I am a new orbeon user. Can you please help out for my query, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213996/where-can-we-get-the-form-data-in-xml-metadata-format-on-click-of-send-button-ev I tried many with multiple builds with number of debug statements but mo use and wasted 3 days to find that simple solution, Any suggestions please

Comment: And for people finding this by chance, follow the link in the previous comment, as that question has since then been answered there by @ebruchez.