# Where can we get the form data in xml/metadata format on click of Send button event?

Tags: xml, scala, orbeon, xforms

I am a new scala learner. As a part of requirement I need to insert the form data in activemq queue for submit event. I tried to debug the send method code to know where exactly do we get the document/form data in xml format on click of send button in "FormRunnerActions.scala" class. Due to my insufficient code analysis I am not able to find where exactly do I get the form data in xml format.

Can anyone please help me the file name/ method name where we can get and save the form data in a string format for send button click event. Once I get the form data (XML format) in string then I will insert the string in  queue.

For Example, If I click send button in contacts form, following form data (xml format) should get in a string variable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><form xmlns:xxi="http://orb
eon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude" xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/X
Include" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xs="h
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xbl="http://www.
w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql" xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.process
or.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner" xmlns:soap="ht
tp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:exf="http://
www.exforms.org/exf/1-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <contact>
        <first-name>Erik</first-name>
        <last-name>Bruchez</last-name>
        <email>info@orbeon.com</email>
        <phone>6505555555</phone>
    </contact>
    <message>
        <order-number>O888</order-number>
        <topic>returns</topic>
        <comments>Please answer me!</comments>
    </message>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We answered that same question in [this forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Insert-form-data-in-Active-MQ-queue-for-send-event-td4659688.html#a4659700).

Comment: Thank you for your response @ebruchez, I will try your suggestion let you know in the forum If I have any queries.